# Backgroundworker not busy

Tags: c#, backgroundworker

I'm sorry for a somewhat blunt question, that could probably have dozens of answers, but I don't even know what to look for...

I am using a background worker, and for some reason, it doesn't seem to get busy.
Before trying to launch the worker, I am checking if it's busy.

The code I have inside it is the follwoing:

```
    void ClientMsg_BgWrkrTimer_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        BackgroundWorker ClientMsg_BgWrkrTimer = sender as BackgroundWorker;
        string current = msgqueue.Last().Key;
        if (msgqueue.Last().Value.t_Type == 0 || msgqueue.Last().Value.t_Type == 1)
        {
            TimedMsgIcon.Enabled = true;
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, UUID> g in Msgqueue.Last().Value.t_ngroups)
            {
                GroupNotice ntc = new GroupNotice();
                ntc.Subject = Msgqueue.Last().Value.t_nmsg;
                ntc.Message = Msgqueue.Last().Value.t_nmsg;
                ntc.OwnerID = Client.Self.AgentID;
                UUID key = UUID.Zero;
                if (UUID.TryParse(Msgqueue.Last().Value.t_attach.ToString(), out key))
                {
                    ntc.AttachmentID = key;
                }
                Client.Self.InstantMessage(Client.Self.Name, g.Value, ntc.Subject + "|" 
                    + ntc.Message, UUID.Zero, InstantMessageDialog.GroupNotice,
                    InstantMessageOnline.Online, Vector3.Zero, UUID.Zero,
                    ntc.SerializeAttachment());
                Thread.Sleep(2000);
            }
        }
    }
```

I have narrowed down the culprit to be this one:

```
    Client.Self.InstantMessage(Client.Self.Name, g.Value, ntc.Subject + "|" 
        + ntc.Message, UUID.Zero, InstantMessageDialog.GroupNotice,
        InstantMessageOnline.Online, Vector3.Zero, UUID.Zero,
        ntc.SerializeAttachment());
```

And most probably it's being the Serialization, which is this (comming from the library I am using):

```
    public struct GroupNotice
    {
        /// <summary></summary>
        public string Subject;
        /// <summary></summary>
        public string Message;
        /// <summary></summary>
        public UUID AttachmentID;
        /// <summary></summary>
        public UUID OwnerID;

        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public byte[] SerializeAttachment()
        {
            if (OwnerID == UUID.Zero || AttachmentID == UUID.Zero)
                return Utils.EmptyBytes;

            OpenMetaverse.StructuredData.OSDMap att = new OpenMetaverse.StructuredData.OSDMap();
            att.Add("item_id", OpenMetaverse.StructuredData.OSD.FromUUID(AttachmentID));
            att.Add("owner_id", OpenMetaverse.StructuredData.OSD.FromUUID(OwnerID));

            return OpenMetaverse.StructuredData.OSDParser.SerializeLLSDXmlBytes(att);
        }
    }
```

The question is, why is this preventing my worker from being busy?
As soon as I take it out, it works like a charm.
I need it though, so I hope anyone could help me suggest what's causing the problem, and how to use it properly in the worker.

Edit:

I'm sorry for missing out the vital point of "Not working"..

So

By "not working", I mean the Client.Self.InstantMessage() doesn't fire off, and the backgroundworker doesn't get bussy.
As mentioned, I test first to see if the worker is busy or not before entering the worker:

```
    void MsgTimer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!ClientSpam_BgWrkrTimer.IsBusy)
        {
            Messagebox.Show("Going into BgWrkr!");
            ClientSpam_BgWrkrTimer.RunWorkerAsync();
        }
    }
```

When using the Client.Self.InstantMessage(), the messagebox keep popping up at every timer tick and the worker never comes to an end.
However, if I remove it, the worker get's completed.

Comment: It might improve your chances of getting a useful answer if you helped your readers understand your definition of "doesn't seem to get busy".  What are you measuring/testing and how does that measurement/test change when you remove your culprit?

Comment: What does "work" mean? What do you expect? What do you get?

Comment: It would also help if you reduced unnecessary detail so your readers are not overwhelmed.  Have you tried building a simple test case that doesn't use msgqueue (whatever type that variable is), GroupNotice and anything else that's not absolutely necessary to reproducing your problem?

Comment: @FrankBoyne Not sure what is supposed to be unnecessary details. :/

Comment: Unnecessary detail would be anything that doesn't contribute to the error happening.  For example, your posted code references msgqueue, TimedMsgIcon and GroupNotice wihout defining any of them.  You _could_ show those definitions but that would make your post even longer and so even less likely to get read.  Create a test case where those variables are not used and your post becomes more readable - and so more likely to get an answer.  Similarly you could simplify your InstantMessage call by using constant values like 0 (or whatever) in place of g.Value and "Test" for ntc.Subject.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I notice that you have a `Thread.Sleep(2000)` statement in your worker.  That will cause the worker's `.IsBusy` property to be true for about 2 seconds, plus whatever time was spent in the method before the `Sleep`.

You also mentioned that when the call to `Client.Self.InstantMessage(...)` is present, then the worker never appears busy.  To me, this seems like the `Thread.Sleep` call is never being executed, which means that it is likely that the `Client.Self.InstantMessage` method is throwing an exception.

Try wrapping the call to `Client.Self.InstantMessage` in a `try/catch` block to see if an exception is being thrown.  You'll be able to observe the message in the Visual Studio Output Window when running in the debugger.

```
        ...

        try
        {    
            Client.Self.InstantMessage(Client.Self.Name, g.Value, ntc.Subject + "|"  
                + ntc.Message, UUID.Zero, InstantMessageDialog.GroupNotice, 
                InstantMessageOnline.Online, Vector3.Zero, UUID.Zero, 
                ntc.SerializeAttachment()); 
        } 
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Exception while calling InstantMessage: {0}", e.ToString());
        }

        Thread.Sleep(2000);

        ...
```

You can also examine the `RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs.Error` property (from the `BackgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted` event) to see if the worker threw an exception.

Once you know what the exception is, you'll be able to better diagnose the cause of the problem.

Comment: I could have sworn I comented this about half an hour ago.. but apparently not. THanks a lot, I don't know why I didn't think of catching the error in a try/catch block.. I am using it elsewhere in the code. Now I got the error message, just gonna work out how to solve it since it's actually comming from whens erializing the attachment. But I'll get there eventually :)